How To Get Date Ranges (As Weeks) In ReactJS/Javascript
I'm trying to pass in a startdate and enddate in the format of YYYY-MM-DD and then have a const return an array whose items represent a date range. Here is the code I have right now that ALMOST works, however there's a weird bug I'll mention in a moment.
Code:
const getWeeksInRange = (startDate, endDate) => {
  const weeks = [];
  // Copy the start date
  let currentDate = new Date(startDate);
  let futureDate = new Date(endDate);
  // Iterate over the range of dates
  while (currentDate <= futureDate) {
    const firstDate = new Date(currentDate); // Copy the current date
    const lastDate = new Date(currentDate); // Copy the current date
    lastDate.setDate(lastDate.getDate() + 6); // Move to the last day of the week

    weeks.push(`${firstDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10)} to ${lastDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10)}`);

    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 7); // Move to the next week
}

  return weeks;
}

An example call would be const resultArray = getWeeksInRange('2024-04-02', '2024-04-30')
This exact call returns:
[ "2024-04-29 to 2024-05-05","2024-04-22 to 2024-04-28", "2024-04-15 to 2024-04-21", "2024-04-08 to 2024-04-14", "2024-04-01 to 2024-05-08", "2024-04-01 to 2024-04-07"]
I am absolutely bashing my brain out trying to see why "2024-04-01 to 2024-05-08" could ever be returned and, when I try and pass in a complete date and time like 2024-04-02T17:12:34.326724+00:00 it does the same thing.
Any information would be greatly appreciated!
Edit: Wanted to add this snippet too, which is having the same issues unfortunately.
  const getSingleWeekRange = (startDate) => {
  const firstDate = new Date(startDate); // Copy the start date
  const lastDate = new Date(startDate); // Copy the start date
  const dayOfWeek = firstDate.getDay(); // Get the day of the week (0-6, where 0 is Sunday)

  // Move the start date to the first day of the week
  firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - dayOfWeek);
  // Move the end date to the last day of the week
  lastDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() + 6);

  return `${firstDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10)} to ${lastDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10)}`;

};

because you are using setDate, it will update Date instead of updating month if it overflows, use setTime in addition to checking, then you check cur <= fut right after you set


const getWeeksInRange = (startDate, endDate) => {
  const weeks = [];
  // Copy the start date
  let currentDate = new Date(startDate);
  let futureDate = new Date(endDate);
  // Iterate over the range of dates
  while (true) {
    const firstDate = new Date(currentDate); // Copy the current date
    const lastDate = new Date(currentDate); // Copy the current date
    
    
    currentDate.setTime(currentDate.getTime() + 7 * 24 * 36e5); // Move to the next week
    if (currentDate > futureDate) break 
    
    
    lastDate.setTime(lastDate.getTime() + 6 * 24 * 36e5); // Move to the last day of the week

    weeks.push(`${firstDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10)} to ${lastDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10)}`);

  }

  return weeks;
}

const resultArray = getWeeksInRange('2024-04-02', '2024-04-30')

console.log( resultArray )




Thank you for this! This seems to be a step in the right direction. Currently this returns 2024-04-01 to 2024-04-07, 2024-04-08 to 2024-04-14, 2024-04-15 to 2024-04-21, 2024-04-22 to 2024-04-28, however it drops the last week (2024-04-29 to 2024-05-05) how can we modify this to also include this date as well?

do you want to take 'May 5, 2024? I think it exceeds '30/04/2024'
